# Variable change for total derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider a variable $x$ and the total derivative w.r.t. $x$. Let's say I want to define

$$x=y_1+y_2$$

where $y_i$ are other variables in the problem. The total differential becomes:

$$dx = dy_1+dy_2$$

Does this mean that the total derivative then becomes:

$$\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dy_1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dy_2}~~~?$$
It seems to me that this should be the case, since we want to maintain $\frac{d}{dx}x=1$. But the factors $1/2$ still seem weird to me. Is this correct? Or maybe I should think of it somehow differently?

Comment: Could you explain how you got from step 2 to 3?

Comment: @Shuri2060 To get to line 3 I think that $(d/dx)x=1$ should hold. In particular this means $(d/dx)(y_1+y_2)=1$. Then if $d/dx$ is to have any variation in both directions $y_1,y_2$ then there should be an overall constant to account for the normalization. So the most straightforward choice is $d/dx=(1/2)(d/dy_1+d/dy_2)$. That's my thought process.

Comment: I don't think I follow after $(d/dx)(y_1+y_2)=1$.

Comment: @Shuri2060 I think of it as a basis. Since $dx= dy_1+dy_2$, we see that there is dependence on both $y_1$ and $y_2$. Then I say: we should be able to express $d/dx$ in the basis of $d/dy_1,d/dy_2$, so that $d/dx=c_1 (d/dy_1)+c_2 (d/dy_2)$. Since $y_1,y_2$ enter the problem completely symmetrically, we have $c_1=c_2=c$, and finally with the normalization constraint $(d/dx)x=1$ we get $c=1/2$.

Comment: I'm not completely comfortable with manipulating objects like $dx$ without clear reasoning derived from the chain rule or similar. I've a feeling that perhaps using it will help explain what you're after better? (or possibly explain why it doesn't - I'm not sure which it is)